# Using Jackson to parse Json map value into String or CustomClass

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm being given a Json file with the form:

```
{
    "descriptions": {
        "desc1": "someString",
        "desc2": {"name":"someName", "val": 7.0}
    }
}
```

I have the POJO:

```
public class CustomClass {
    Map<String, Object> descriptions;
    public static class NameVal{
        String name;
        double val;
        public NameVal(String name, double val){...}
    }
}
```

I can recreate the json file with the code:

```
CustomClass a = new CustomClass();
a.descriptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
a.descriptions.put("desc1", "someString");
a.descriptions.put("desc2", new CustomClass.NameVal("someName", 7.0));
new ObjectMapper().writeValue(new File("testfile"), a);
```

But, when I read the object back in using:

```
CustomClass fromFile = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File("testfile"), CustomClass.class);
```

then fromFile.descriptions.get("desc2") is of type LinkedHashMap instead of type CustomClass.NameVal.

How can I get Jackson to properly parse the type of the CustomClass.NameVal descriptors (other than making some class that wraps the parsing and explicitly converts the LinkedHashMap after Jackson reads the file)?

Comment: Jackson can guess many things but not this kind of things... You need to annotate the map to guide jackson into how to deserialize this map's values. It cannot make up much out of `Object` as a value type!

Comment: and there's no nice way for me to hook into the deserialization process, recognize my POJO and tell Jackson to parse into that instead of a LinkedHashMap?

Comment: You need to write a custom deserializer for what you want to do. It's entirely out of the happy path for both Jackson and Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Create a class Description with name and value attributes:

```
public class Description {
    private String name;
    private double val;
}
```

Now in your CustomClass do this:

```
public class CustomClass {
     List<Description> descriptions;
}
```

And that's it. Remember to create getters and setters because Jackson needs it.

Comment: This does not parse the provided Json. The value of "desc1" is a string, not a String/Double Description.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
public class DescriptionWrapper {
    private Description descriptions;

    public Description getDescriptions() {
        return descriptions;
    }

    public void setDescriptions(Description descriptions) {
        this.descriptions = descriptions;
    }
}

public class Description {
    private String desc1;
    private NameValue desc2;

    public String getDesc1() {
        return desc1;
    }

    public void setDesc1(String desc1) {
        this.desc1 = desc1;
    }

    public NameValue getDesc2() {
        return desc2;
    }

    public void setDesc2(NameValue desc2) {
        this.desc2 = desc2;
    }
}

public class NameValue {
    private String name;
    private double val;

    public String getName() {
         return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
    }

    public double getVal() {
         return val;
    }

    public void setVal(double val) {
         this.val = val;
    }
}
```